# Concurrent access to elements in the same cacheline in non-shared cache on x86-64

Tags: linux, concurrency, x86-64, cache-control

Assume I have the following code:

```
int x[200];

void thread1() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    x[i*2] = 1;
}

void thread2() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    x[i*2 + 1] = 1;
}
```

Is the code correct in x86-64 memory model (from what I understand it is) assuming the page was configured with default write cache policy in Linux? What is the impact on performance of such code (from what I understand - none)?

PS. As of performance - I am mostly interested in Sandy Bridge.

**EDIT:** As of expectation - I want to write to aligned locations from different threads. I expect the upper code after finishing and barrier to contains `{1,1,1, ...}` in `x` rather then `{0,1,0,1,...}` or `{1,0,1,0,...}`.

Comment: "Is the code correct" implies you have some expectations out of it. What are those? Are the elements write-only (apparently yes)? Who else is reading them, and are they doing so to both of them or just one at a time? Is there a deterministic pattern? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis: I have numerous writes to different location from threads (the threads are independent and does not write to exactly the same location and does not read the data). I want to ensure cache coherency (check on x86) and performance on Sandy Bridge (check due to Quick Path). I hope that edit explained what I expect (this part was rather to ensure I forgot about something as I was fairly sure about cache coherency - but better to be safe then sorry).

Comment: @Maciej SandyBridge is DMI, not QPI, Nehalem was QPI.

Comment: @Marcin: From what I understend you are right as far as the 'outside' of processor is concerned. In the rings the SB uses 'enhanced' QPI (http://www.realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT091810191937&p=8 - the page was linked from Wikipedia so I assume it's correct - http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sandy_Bridge&oldid=448105707).

Comment: @Maciej, so what is considered 'outside' vs 'inside' then?  Are other core's caches considered inside, but PCI-e bus an outside, or something more convoluted than that?

Comment: @Marcin: Other cores are 'inside' while PCI-e, memory etc. are 'outside'. Sandy Bridge splitted FSB into faster part inside processor between cores and L3 cache and outside where it communicates with memory etc. (or at least as far as I understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the writes will eventually propagate by snooping requests . The Sandy Bridge uses Quick Path between cores so the snooping would not hit FSB but would use much quicker interconnection. As it is not based on cache-invalidation-on-write it should be 'fairly' quick although I wasn't able to find what is the overhead of conflict resolution (but probably lower then L3 write).

[Source](http://www.realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT072011132706&p=3)

**EDIT**: According to [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) clean hit have impact of 43 cycles and dirty hit have impact of 60 cycles (compared with 4 cycles normal overhead for L1, 12 for L2 and 26-31 for L3).